# TextSwitcher setText in a loop is not working properly?

Tags: android

I am writing an Android app like a number wheeler. I used TextSwitcher and a loop to change the text. It is supposed that each number in the loop will slide from left to right. But the result is not as expected. Only the last number slide in, it seems no number is slided out. Can anyone help with this? Is this related to UI update?

Here are my codes.

```
package net.pixelstech.counter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextSwitcher;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory{
private TextSwitcher mSwitcher;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSwitcher=(TextSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.count_id);
    mSwitcher.setFactory(this);

    mSwitcher.setInAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    GeneralCountAsyncTask cat=new GeneralCountAsyncTask();
    cat.execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public View makeView() {
    TextView t = new TextView(this);
    t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    t.setTextSize(70);
    t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    return t;
}

private void startAnimate(final int from,final int to){
    for(int i=from;i<to;++i){
        mSwitcher.setText(String.valueOf(i));   
    }
}

public class GeneralCountAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,String,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...v){
        while(true){
            try {
                publishProgress("");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String...values){
        startAnimate(1,3);
    }
}
}
```

Here is the xml I am using:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextSwitcher android:id="@+id/count_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
>
</TextSwitcher>
```

Hope someone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting the slide right animation before the slide left? I have tried a fade animation with image and text switcher and faced a similar problem.